# Angular textarea with autocomplete/suggestions

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I'm working with Angular and I want to create a textarea that works similar to text editors(vs code ...)
which means I can write a word such as text1. and it give me suggestions from a list of date that relate to text1 (something similar to the attached images)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try libraries like https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: I'd suggest to look at https://codemirror.net/ It is not easy but not too complex either.

Comment: i am not working with angularJs so i don't think this will work

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is complicated, not impossible, but complicated.

Mainly you should have a data structure that makes reference to all the classes already defined in the language you are trying to help (for example an array of class names), and within each one of them, all the available methods, with your list of required parameters.

After interpreting each keystroke to know what class name to write, and after a period, the method that may exist.

Very complicated to explain by this means.

Best of luck and greetings.

Comment: thanks for replaying,i am not tring to replicate a code editor ,i have my own liste of item that should be suggested .Imagine if i have a liste of names (jhon,mark,brad) and each of them have a details (age,id,salary) when user start to write he can press as exemple shift+space he get the names liste then wen he add a dot he gets a the details liste